# example of an external table which accepts all records from a file

Tags: sql, oracle

Please can any one tell me how to accept all records from a file so that no record should go to  discard or bad file  using external table concept.

Below is the code

```
 CREATE TABLE ext_tab2 (  
    mprn CHAR(10))   
    ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (   
      TYPE ORACLE_LOADER   
      DEFAULT DIRECTORY IMPORT   
        ACCESS PARAMETERS (   
        RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE  
        BADFILE IMPORT:'test.bad'    
        LOGFILE IMPORT:'test.log'    
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','   
        (mprn char(10)))     
        LOCATION ('abc.txt')   
        )   
        PARALLEL 5   
    REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

All the data from file('abc.txt') should get inserted into ext_tab2  table .

Comment: Why wouldn't all records be visible in the table?

Comment: if the column(mprn) is given as  number(data type) in that file so it will reject the record and put it in BAD file generated as part of this external table concept.So i want that record to be inserted into external table